# The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building ...Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a payment method through the paid market, but when I call "Navigator.of(context).push(
MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => TelaDadosPix(resultado))));" it says that null is being passed instead of string

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:mercadopago_sdk/mercadopago_sdk.dart';
import 'package:mp_flutter/mp_flutter.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:horario/core/configs/route.dart';
import 'package:horario/features/pix/presentation/tela_dados_pix.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class CriaChavePix extends StatefulWidget {
  Map<String, dynamic> dadosPix;
  CriaChavePix(this.dadosPix);

  @override
  _CriaChavePix createState() => _CriaChavePix();
}

class _CriaChavePix extends State<CriaChavePix> {
  String chavePix = '';

  Future<void> criaChavePix() async {
    var bodyMap = {
      "transaction_amount": 2000,
      "payment_method_id": "pix",
      "payer": {
        "email": "test@mail.com",
        "first_name": "first_name",
        "last_name": "last_name",
        "identification": {
          "type": "identification_type",
          "number": "number_cpf"
        }
      }
    };

    var url = Uri.parse('https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/');

    var response = await http.post(url,
        headers: {
          "Authorization":
              "Bearer ...",
        },
        body: json.encode(bodyMap));

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      Map<String, dynamic> resultado = json.decode(response.body);

      Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => TelaDadosPix(resultado))));
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.body);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    criaChavePix();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building TelaDadosPix(dirty, state: _TelaDadosPix#e6117):
Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  TelaDadosPix
TelaDadosPix:file:///C:/Users/pedro/OneDrive/%C3%81rea%20de%20Trabalho/Horario/horario/lib/features/pix/presentation/cria_chave_pix.dart:52:52
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 127:3       castError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 742:12  cast
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 674:17                as
packages/horario/features/pix/presentation/tela_dados_pix.dart 50:21              build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5409:27                               build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5297:15                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5462:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5016:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5279:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5273:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4182:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3707:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6434:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4182:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3707:18                               updateChild
```

the error is this one above

it is saying that the error is at 52:52 which would be this part of the code: ((context) => TelaDadosPix(resultado))

when you click on TelaDadosPix, you don't even get to the (resultado) in TelaDadosPix

The class TelaDadosPix

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TelaDadosPix extends StatefulWidget {
  Map<String, dynamic> dadosPix;

  TelaDadosPix(this.dadosPix);

  _TelaDadosPix createState() => _TelaDadosPix();
}

class _TelaDadosPix extends State<TelaDadosPix> {
  String statusPix = " ";

  Future<void> pesquisaStatusPix() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/');
    var response =
        await http.post(url, body: {"idPix": widget.dadosPix["idPIX"]});

    statusPix = response.body;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/img_pix.jpeg",
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Status do Pagamento Pix:",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    Text(widget.dadosPix["status"],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.green)),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16.0,
                    ),
                    Text(widget.dadosPix["total_a_pagar"].toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.green))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                        height: 36,
                        width: 36,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/um.png",
                        )),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                            "Abra o app do seu banco ou seu app de pagamentos.",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black)))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                        height: 36,
                        width: 36,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/dois.png",
                        )),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text("Busque á opção de pagar com pix.",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black)))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                        height: 36,
                        width: 36,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/tres.png",
                        )),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text("Copie e cole o seguinte código.",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black)))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          widget.dadosPix["qr_code"],
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 44.0,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      final data =
                          ClipboardData(text: widget.dadosPix["qr_code"]);
                      Clipboard.setData(data);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "COPIAR CHAVE",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12.0,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do `debugPrint('$resultado');` above the `Navigator` call, then update us what it prints.

Comment: @Cabdirashiid here it is

Comment: I don't see it in the image. I meant copy & paste the debugPrint. But, nevermind. Sorry the error is at TelaDadosPix class. Can you post the code to that page? BTW, you may not want to post Authorization bearer tokens in public, for security. [learn more](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/10/06/best-practices-for-authentication-and-authorization-for-rest-apis/)

Comment: the class TelaDadosPix is here @Cabdirashiid

Comment: I've used your code & the authorization bearer token to the API for testing. I hope you don't mind. You may regenerate a new token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a `Text` widget. dadosPix was a `Map` & `widget.dadosPix["qr_code"]` was returning null. the "qr_code" key was in children of children of the json response.

`["point_of_interaction"]["transaction_data"]["qr_code"]` should get you the value.

Widget causing the issue.

```dart
Text(
  widget.dadosPix["qr_code"],
  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
)
```

**Solution:**

```dart
Text(
  widget.dadosPix["point_of_interaction"]["transaction_data"]["qr_code"],
  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
)
```

Comment: thanks man it works!

Comment: When your question is answered, may you accept the correct answer by clicking the checkmark. It may help others know this question was solved. Comments are usually for clarification.